# how to quantize the image to MxN blocks

Tags: java, image, graphics, ascii

Certainly, I am writing a program about Image to ASCII Conversion. I have already convert the image to grayscale, but I don't know to write the code of quantizing the image to MxN blocks

1. For every sub-image of MxN size, compute its average gray value
2. Store the computed average gray value to a new image).

Here is the program:

```
public static char[][] imageToASCII(Image img, int blockWidth, int blockHeight)
{
    {
        // Convert image from type Image to BufferedImage
        BufferedImage bufImg = convert(img);

        // Scan through each row of the image
        for(int j=0; j<bufImg.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            // Scan through each columns of the image
            for(int i=0; i<bufImg.getWidth(); i++)
            {
                // Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model
                int values=bufImg.getRGB(i,j);
                // Convert the single integer pixel value to RGB color
                Color oldColor = new Color(values);

                int red = oldColor.getRed();        // get red value
                int green = oldColor.getGreen();    // get green value
                int blue = oldColor.getBlue();  // get blue value

                // Convert RGB to grayscale using formula
                // gray = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
                double grayVal = 0.299*red + 0.587*green + 0.114*blue;

                // Assign each channel of RGB with the same value
                Color newColor = new Color((int)grayVal, (int)grayVal, (int)grayVal);

                // Get back the integer representation of RGB color
                // and assign it back to the original position
            bufImg.setRGB(i, j, newColor.getRGB());

        }           
    return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to divide the image into blocks of MxN size. This is similar to the Microblock in video coding.